# Google API get Company/Organization Name

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-admin-settings-api

How do I get the company or organization name using Google's API?

I see an option for this under the Admin SDK via the Admin Settings section, but the API request always returns 'authentication required'.  I am able to process other API requests that start with https://www.googleapis.com just fine.  I am sending the access_token with these calls.

Is there a way outside of the Admin Settings API section that would allow me to get this information?  If not, what are some common reasons that might be causing my API response to be 'authentication required'

Answer (score 0):

From the [Authenticating to the Admin Settings API service](https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/) guide, have you included the Admin Setting OAuth scope below in your token request?

```
https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/domain/
```

Comment: Yes, this is included in my scope.

Comment: Would there happen to be an alternative method to get the company name other then the Admin Settings API?